# Campos Checkbox Vindo do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

Tenho 3 tabelas, respetivamente:

- **Veiculos**

  - *veiculo_id, veiculo_nome*.
- **Acessorios**

  - *acessorio_id, acessorio_nome*
- **Veiculos_acessorios**

  - *veiculo_id*
  - *acessorio_id*

Na página de cadastro de veículo os campos *acessorios* vêm do banco de dados da tabela *acessorios* como um campo do tipo *checkbox*. Quando faço o cadastro do veículo, o cadastro é inserido nas tabelas *veiculos* e *veiculos_acessorios*.

Até esta parte funciona normalmente, mas na página de *editar* consigo pegar apenas os que já foram marcados *(pelo checkbox)* durante o cadastro do veículo, e o que eu queria era mostrar todos os acessórios da tabela, incluindo os não marcados, deixando apenas marcados os que foram marcados durante o cadastro.

O código da consulta SQL da página de editar está assim: Nessa consulta só retorna os checkboxs que foram marcados no cadastro!

```
<?php 
$getVehicleID = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'vehicleID', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);       

$ReadItens = new Read;
$ReadItens->FullRead("SELECT cars.car_id,car_vehicles_and_items.car_id,car_additional.additional_id,car_additional.additional_title
FROM car_vehicles_and_items INNER JOIN cars ON cars.car_id = car_vehicles_and_items.car_id 
INNER JOIN car_additional ON car_additional.additional_id = car_vehicles_and_items.additional_id where car_vehicles_and_items.car_id  = : id", " id=$getVehicleID");

foreach ($ReadItens->getResult() as $lisItens):

echo "<input ";

if ($lisItens['car_id'] == $getVehicleID):  

echo "checked ";
endif;

echo "type=\"checkbox\" id=\"{$lisItens['additional_id']}\"  name=\"car_additional[]\" value=\"{$lisItens['additional_id']}\">";
echo $lisItens['additional_title'];
endforeach;
```

[image: Na página de cadastro os acessórios estão assim]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que você já tem feito? Esta criando o HTML diretamente por um arquivo PHP? Por que existem diferentes formas de fazer. Edite a pergunta com o código que já foi feito nessa parte.

Comment: não entendi muito bem o que voce está querendo fazer, voce quer buscar no banco de dados os valores e coloca-los em uma checkbox com a marcação ativa? é isso?

Comment: Sim é isso mesmo quero listar todos os acessórios e ficar ativos só os que foram marcados no cadastro!

Comment: Apesar da edição, continua a ser difícil entender o que queres realmente.

Comment: pelo que estou entendendo, é só arrancar o filtro dos "checked": `" id=$getVehicleID"`  da consulta.

Comment: Trás tudo sem filtro, no loop, você marca o que estiver checado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que estou vendo, seu problema é de condição, você está trazendo só os inputs marcados, neste caso, basta você colocar todos e ignorar o filtro, olha só como você poderia fazer isso:

```
$getVehicleID = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'vehicleID', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);  

$ReadItens = new Read;
$ReadItens->FullRead("
      SELECT cars.car_id,
             car_vehicles_and_items.car_id,
             car_additional.additional_id,
             car_additional.additional_title
      FROM   car_vehicles_and_items 
      LEFT JOIN cars
             ON cars.car_id = car_vehicles_and_items.car_id
      LEFT JOIN car_additional 
             ON car_additional.additional_id = car_vehicles_and_items.additional_id
      WHERE :n", " n=1");

foreach ($ReadItens->getResult() as $lisItens) {

    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" " . 
         "id=\"{$lisItens['additional_id']}\" ";
         "name=\"car_additional[]\ " .
         "value=\"{$lisItens['additional_id']}\"" . 
         (($lisItens['car_id'] == $getVehicleID) ? 'checked = \"checked\"' : '') .
         ">" . $lisItens['additional_title'];
}
```

Comment: Só retornou os 4 resultado do checkbox!

Comment: porque sua consulta deve executar só isso mesmo. tente mudar para LEFT JOIN

Comment: Estranho pois removi a comparação  para `WHERE 1`; To achando que essa sua consulta é baseada nos registros do usuário e não da tabela que contém todas as categorias.

Comment: Eu usei o LEFT JOIN e deu certo valeu!

Comment: A query ficou assim deu certo :  $ReadItens = new Read;
$ReadItens->ExeRead('car_additional', "LEFT JOIN car_vehicles_and_items on car_vehicles_and_items.additional_id = car_additional.additional_id");

Answer (score 1):

Ok... acredito que o jeito mais simples de você resolver essa questão seja:

1 - criar uma query para listar todos os acessórios cadastrados
2 - criar uma query para recuperar todos os acessórios que o veiculo XPTO possui. Faça o while do resultado da query e armazene em um array.
3 - quando você fizer o loop do item "1" (que lista os acessórios cadastrados), faça um if:

```
if (in_array($linhaDoLoopDoItem1, $arrayDoItem2)) { 
    echo "checked";
}
```

Lembrando que esse IF precisa estar dentro da tag checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar esse único select que irá retornar tanto os acessórios em um determinado carro quanto os que não estão.

`SELECT A.ACESSORIO_ID, A.ACESSORIO_NOME, "TRUE" CHECKED
  FROM ACESSORIOS A
  JOIN VEICULOS_ACESSORIOS  VA
    ON VA.ACESSORIO_ID = A.ACESSORIO_ID
 WHERE VA.VEICULO_ID = X 
 UNION 
SELECT A.ACESSORIO_ID, A.ACESSORIO_NOME, 'FALSE'
  FROM ACESSORIOS A
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM VEICULOS V
                     JOIN VEICULOS_ACESSORIOS  VA
                       ON VA.ACESSORIO_ID = A.ACESSORIO_ID
                    WHERE V.VEICULO_ID = VA.VEICULO_ID
                      AND V.VEICULO_ID = X)`

Comment: Só retornou os 4 resultado do checkbox!

Comment: Por favor, veja a edição.

Comment: Erro no código [Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'A.ACESSORIO_ID' in 'on clause'

Comment: Por favor, verifique os campos para ver se estão com a nomenclatura correta.

Comment: Verifiquei estão todos certos.